# Can't select any code signing identities in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode

I've tried and tried, but for some reason I can't select any code signing identities in Xcode 4.1.  When I click it, it just presents a text input instead.  I have a developer profile installed via organizer and a provisioning profile to match it.  I've already completely removed xcode and re-installed it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The default value of "iPhone Developer" is generally sufficient.

Comment: That's the problem.  Nothing at all shows up.  Just an empty text area.  If it helps, I'm part of an enterprise developer license.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The solution for the problem is quite easy just go to Editors>Show Values on Xcode then you can select the code sign instead of typing

Comment: i install phone gap and command line tool but after changing path by following command  sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer     when i am going to change code sign profile it will now give me any option for select profile  .. before this (clt and phonegap) it will give me more profile to choose but now it not show me more profile ... :( it gives me one profile only and when i click on it,it shows iPhone Distribution: XXX
7A4DA-76-49AA-BB8D-807488B. my bundle id and profile are valid .. if i want to change bundle id and change profile what i have to do.